# ext.net Error : Control with type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' cannot be handled by layout

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource, ext.net

i have a web form .inside of this ,i am loading usercontroler via 
`<ext:UserControlLoader` .
my user controler contains an sqldatasource.when i run the page ,i got the error something like this "Control with type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' cannot be handled by layout".

my web form is like this;

```
 <ext:ResourceManager ID="ResourceManager1" runat="server" />
   <ext:Panel runat="server">
   <Items>
  <ext:UserControlLoader ID="UserControlLoader4" runat="server" Path="~/Controlers/SinifListe.ascx" />
   </Items>
 </panel>
```

and my usercontroler

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AProjeConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Sinif]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<ext:Panel runat="server" ID="mainpanelone" Title="listele" Flex="1" BodyStyle="background-color:#DFE9F6">
    <Items>
                <ext:Container ID="Container1" runat="server" Layout="HBoxLayout" Flex="1">
                    <Items>
                         <ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel2" runat="server" Title="Sınıf " Frame="true"  Width="300">
                            <Store>
                                <ext:Store ID="Store2" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
                                    <Model>
                                        <ext:Model ID="Model2" runat="server" IDProperty="Id">
                                            <Fields>
                                                <ext:ModelField Name="Id" />
                                                <ext:ModelField Name="Ad" />
                                            </Fields>
                                        </ext:Model>
                                    </Model>
                                </ext:Store>
                            </Store>
                            <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel2" runat="server">
                                <Columns>
                                    <ext:Column ID="Column1" runat="server" DataIndex="Id" Text="Id" />
                                    <ext:Column ID="Column2" runat="server" DataIndex="Ad" Text="Ad" />
                                </Columns>
                            </ColumnModel>
                        </ext:GridPanel>
                    </Items>
                </ext:Container>
    </Items>
</ext:Panel>
```

how can i solve this problem.
*i put sqldatasources inside of the  web form and problem solved,however, i wanna use sqldatasources inside of my usercontroler

**i make simple web form and usercontroler to be understandable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can place the `SqlDataSource` into the inner `<HtmlBin>` property of the `<ext:GridPanel>`.

**Example**

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="GridPanel2...
    <HtmlBin>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2"...
    </HtmlBin>
</ext:GridPanel>
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** Changed `<Bin>` to `<HtmlBin>`

Comment: when i did that , i got the error something like this;          Parser Error Message: Ext.Net.ItemsCollection`1[[Ext.Net.Observable, Ext.Net, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=2e12ce3d0176cd87]] must have items of type 'Ext.Net.Observable'. 'asp:SqlDataSource' is of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource'.

Comment: sorry, my mistake. You should be able to use <HtmlBin>, not <Bin>